# Qual a diferença do forEach do angular e a função map do javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, programação-funcional

Gostaria de saber qual a diferença entre utilizar o `angular.forEach` e a função `map` do Javascript.

ex:

```
angular.forEach(meuArray, function(itens) {...})

meuArray.map(function(itens) {...});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O `map` do Javascript só vai funcionar em valores do tipo `Array`, porque faz parte do seu prototype. Ou seja, o `map` a que você se refere trata-se do `Array.prototype.map`.

Já o `angular.forEach` (que é uma função disponível apenas quando se usa o  framework AngularJs) funciona tanto para `Array` como para `Object`.

O `Array.prototype.map`, além disso, retorna valores mapeados para um novo `Array` ao final da iteração. Já o  `angular.forEach` não faz isso, ele apenas percorre (o valor retornado é o mesmo passado, sem alteração).

Nesse exemplo, um novo array será criado:

```js
var multipos_de_3 = [1, 2, 3].map(function (value) {
       return value * 3;
})

console.log(multipos_de_3);
```

Já nesse, os valores serão mantidos

```js
var retorno = angular.forEach([1, 2, 3], function (value, key) {

      return value * 3;
});

console.log(retorno);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Na verdade ambas as funções são do Javasscript. A diferença entre `forEach` e `map` é a funcionalidade. `forEach` itera todos os valores do array, enquanto o `map` retorna um novo array, pois tem a funcionalidade de mapear.

Por exemplo esse array de objetos:

```
[{ 'nome', 'João',
   'idade', 20
},{ 'nome', 'José',
   'idade', 30
}]
```

Para obter somente o nome desses objetos, com `forEach` ficaria:

```
var nomes = [];
array.forEach(function(item){
  nomes.push(item.nome);
});
```

A mesma operação com `map`:

```
var nomes = array.map(item => item.nome);
```

Ambos irão retornar o array:

```
['João', 'José']
```

Comment: -1. Ele não está falando do `forEach` do Javascript, e sim do `angular.forEach`.

Comment: Qual a diferença entre o `forEach` do angular para o do Javascript @WallaceMaxters?

Comment: Minha resposta já diz. Não existe `forEach` em `Object` em Javascript.

Comment: Nesse ponto ponto você está certo. Não me atentei que ele está se referindo ao `forEach` implementado somente no angular. Mas vou deixar minha resposta porquê apresentei uma diferença básica a implementação canônica entre os dois. Obrigado :)