# Qual a diferença entre forEach e map no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, array

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

arr.forEach(i => i);

arr.map(i => i);
```

Eu gostaria de entender qual a diferença entre os métodos `forEach` e `map` no JavaScript.

Comment: duplicada? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/169270/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-do-foreach-do-angular-e-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-map-do-javascript

Comment: @AnittaDeveloper e Augusto - Eu quase indiquei essa duplicata também, mas vi que ela fala sobre o `angular.forEach`, que apesar de parecido, não é exatamente igual ao `forEach` nativo do JavaScript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39212839 - Apesar do funcionamento geral ser o mesmo para arrays, achei melhor responder em vez de indicar a duplicata...

Comment: @AnittaDeveloper não é duplicata, o [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) é completamente diferente do [`angular.forEach()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach)

Comment: Eu estou retirando meu voto para fechar pois o hkotsubo e o Arthur Siqueira tem razão.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Qual a diferença do forEach do angular e a função map do javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/169270/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-do-foreach-do-angular-e-a-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-map-do-javascript)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) serve para percorrer o array e fazer alguma coisa com os seus elementos. Mas essa "alguma coisa" não necessariamente precisa retornar algo (tanto que o [seu retorno](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Return_value) é `undefined`). Ex:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// só imprime o dobro dos elementos (não retorna nenhum valor)
arr.forEach(e => console.log(e * 2));
```

No fundo o código acima é só uma forma diferente de se fazer um `for` tradicional:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    console.log(arr[i] * 2);
```

---

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), por sua vez, faz alguma operação com cada elemento, e [**retorna outro array**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Return_value) contendo o resultado desta operação:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// gera outro array contendo o dobro de cada elemento
const dobros = arr.map(e => e * 2);

console.log(dobros); // [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

---

Obviamente que `map` precisa percorrer o array para poder executar a operação e gerar um novo array contendo os resultados, mas usá-lo **somente** para percorrer o array é um "uso torto".

Comment: Quando aparece uma pergunta respondível sempre tem alguém mais rápido do que eu.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Eu dei sorte, entrei no site e dei de cara com a pergunta :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo eu perdi tempo com as referências hehehehe ;p

Answer (score 6):

Segundo o [site da Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> O método `map()` invoca a função `callback` passada por argumento para cada elemento do Array e devolve um novo Array como resultado.
>
> [...]
>
> O método map não modifica o array original. No entanto, a função callback invocada por ele pode fazê-lo.

Ainda [segundo o mesmo](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> O método `forEach()` executa uma dada função em cada elemento de um array.

Em resumo, o método `Array.prototype.map()` retorna um novo vetor com as modificações geradas, enquanto o `Array.prototype.forEach()` executa as funções no vetor original (tanto que `forEach()` retorna `undefined`).

Para funções didáticas, vou recriar o funcionamento de ambas funções abaixo.

A função `forEach` pode ser "traduzida" como:

```
function forEach(vetor, funcaoCallback){
    for(let x = 0; x < vetor.length; x++){
        funcaoCallback(vetor[x]);
    }
}
```

Enquanto a função `map()` pode ser "traduzida" como:

```
function map(vetor, funcaoCallback){
    let ans = [];
    for(let x = 0; x < vetor.length; x++){
        ans.push(funcaoCallback(vetor[x]));
    }
    return ans
}
```

Ambos possuem outras diferenças, como velocidade, e demais aspectos técnicos, como visto nos links abaixo:

- [JavaScript — Map vs. ForEach (inglês)](https://codeburst.io/javascript-map-vs-foreach-f38111822c0f);
- [JavaScript: Entendendo a diferença entre map x forEach](https://medium.com/@programadriano/javascript-entendendo-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-map-x-foreach-366a77fc7e82);