# Como agrupar dados por intervalo de tempo?

Tags: javascript, objetos

Preciso reunir valores recebidos entre um determinado intervalo de tempo, com javscript.

Tenho um object:

```
var object = [
    { horario: "09:03", status: "OK"},
    { horario: "09:04", status: "OK"},
    { horario: "09:05", status: "NOK" },
    { horario: "09:06", status: "OK"},
    { horario: "09:07", status: "NOK"},
    { horario: "09:07", status: "OK"},
    { horario: "09:08", status: "NOK"},
];
```

E quero um retorno parecido com isso:

```
retorno: [{
    status: ["OK", "OK", "NOK"],
    horario: ["09:05"]
}, {
    status: ["OK", "OK", "NOK", "NOK"]
    horario: ["09:10"]
}]
```

O que tentei fazer, até agora, foi isso aqui:

```
//Declaração do objeto, que também poderia ser um array
var object = [
    { horario: "09:03", status: "OK"},
    { horario: "09:04", status: "OK"},
    { horario: "09:05", status: "NOK" },
    { horario: "09:06", status: "OK"},
    { horario: "09:07", status: "NOK"},
    { horario: "09:07", status: "OK"},
    { horario: "09:08", status: "NOK"},
]; 

//Declaração de contadores, e arrays que receberão os dados
var x = [];
var y = [];
var a = 0;
var b = 0;

//Laço para percorrer o objeto
for (var i = 0; i < status.length; i++) {
                    
    if (status[i] == "OK") {
        a++;
        b = b+0;
        x.push(x[i] = a);
        y.push(y[i] = b);
    } else if (status[i] == "NOK") {
        a = a+0;
        b++;
        x.push(x[i] = a);
        y.push(y[i] = b);
    }
}
```

Até funciona, mas não como deveria. O que posso fazer para resolver esse problema?

Comment: Perdão, você pode sugerir uma alteração?

Comment: *Como organizar os dados pelo status.* Também seria bom colocar um [MCVE] mostrando sua tentativa em solucionar o problema, não estou dizendo que seja o seu caso, mas muita gente tenta nos usar para resolver tarefa de casa "sem esforço" e normalmente código que venha desacompanhado de tentativa de resolução a comunidade negativa.

Comment: Okay, obrigado pela ajuda!!! Irei implementar essas melhorias na pergunta

Comment: A hora que você colocar o [MCVE] você ganha um +1.

Comment: Melhorou???????

Comment: Não! Saiu fora do escopo e jogou a resposta fora de escopo. É só exemplo **mínimo** do que como tentou resolver o mesmo problema que apresentou. Se quiser perguntar sobre outro conteúdo abra uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Entendi. Acho que vou abrir outra pergunta, e melhorar essa aqui ao mesmo tempo. Alguma sugestão para o título da outra questão?

Comment: Eu estou saindo para almoçar depois do almoço posso até dar uma sugestão.

Comment: Tá bem, obrigado, Augusto

Answer (score -1):

Você pode utilizar a função [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro) (desta forma irá retornar somente quando a comparação for True) ou [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro) (percorre o Array uma unica vez e você faz a validação dentro dele)

```
var object = [
    { horario: "09:03", status: "OK"},
    { horario: "09:04", status: "OK"},
    { horario: "09:05", status: "NOK" },
    { horario: "09:06", status: "OK"},
    { horario: "09:07", status: "NOK"},
    { horario: "09:07", status: "OK"},
    { horario: "09:08", status: "NOK"},
];
//Filter
var filterOk = object.filter(j => j.status == "OK")
var filterNOk = object.filter(j => j.status == "NOK")

//ForEach Desta forma percorre somente uma vez o array
var filterOk = []
var filterNOk = []
object.forEach( ar => {
  if (ar.status =='OK') { 
    filterOk.push(ar.horario) 
  } else {
    filterNOk.push(ar.horario)
  }})


var retorno = {"OK": filterOk, "NOK": filterNOk}
```

Comment: Coloquei o link para documentação do método filter. Se achar que a mudança descaracteriza a resposta você pode reverter [clicando sobre a revisão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/490009/revisions).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, amigo!

Comment: O `map` não é ideal para realizar iterações "só por iterar". O `map` em tese deve ser utilizado para _mapear_ um array em outro. Nesse caso acho que valeria mais a pena utilizar um `forEach` ou um laço de repetição como `for`, não? :)

Comment: Complementando o comentário acima, usar `map` **só** para iterar não é uma boa porque ele retorna outro array (que no seu caso, está sendo ignorado) - é um array diferente dos que vc já criou (`filterOk` e `filterNok`), com o resultado do *callback* - mas como o *callback* não retorna nada, o resultado será um monte de `undefined` - [veja](https://ideone.com/WDDlq4). Se você só quer iterar pelo array, de fato o melhor seria usar um `for` simples (ou então o `forEach` - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/426824/112052). Apesar de "funcionar", `map` não é o mais indicado neste caso

Comment: Alterei minha resposta.