# Filtrar um resultado dentro de um array de objeto em javaScript

Tags: javascript, array, map

```
let result = [
  {
    Id: 3787135,
    Document: '1111111111',
    Idade: 20,
    Sexo: 'M',
    IsActive: true
    },
  {
    Id: 3965111,
    Document: '2222222222',
    Idade: 30,
    Sexo: 'F',
    IsActive: true
  },
  {
    Id: 4446170,
    Document: '33333333',
    Idade: 50,
    Sexo: 'M',
    IsActive: true
  }
]
```

Preciso retornar apenas um array filtrando pelo 'Id', dessa forma:

```
4446170;33333333;50;M;true
```

Tentei isso:

```
  let ids = '4446170';

  result.map(x => item = x);

   const item2 = item.find(x => 
    x.Id.includes(ids)
);
console.log(item2.Id+';'+item2.Document+';'+item2.Idade+';'+item2.Sexo+';'+item2.IsActive)
```

Porém não obtive sucesso, solicito ajudo por favor.

Comment: Apesar da pergunta indicada acima no box azul não ser 100% exatamente igual, o problema é basicamente o mesmo: encontrar elemento(s) do array com base em algum critério. E lá já tem as 2 opções: usar `find` (traz somente o primeiro encontrado) ou `filter` (traz todos que satisfazem a condição). No seu caso, bastaria fazer `item = result.find(x => x.Id === 4446170)` (afinal, vc quer o Id igual a 4446170, não faz sentido usar `includes`). E depois para juntar os valores, poderia ser `Object.values(item).join(';')` (a menos que vc queira eles em uma ordem diferente, mas a princípio deve servir).

Comment: Outro detalhe é que vc chamou `map`, mas esta função retorna **outro** array, só que vc não usa esse retorno para nada. De qualquer forma, o `map` no seu caso é desnecessário e pode ser removido (veja mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/426824/112052))