# Calcular média dentro de um array e dentro de um objeto

Tags: javascript

Eu fiz o código abaixo onde declarei um aluno, depois criei 5 alunos e agora necessito fazer a média dentro do `array` de notas, e tem que me voltar a informação de média de cada aluno dentro desse "banco de alunos". A função está me voltando `NaN` preciso de ajuda para resolver essa questão.

```
function Aluno(nome, qtfaltas, nota) {
  this.nome = nome;
  this.qtfaltas = qtfaltas;
  this.nota = nota;
}

let Aluno1 = new Aluno("Jose Silva", 0, [0,10,20]);
let Aluno2 = new Aluno("Paulo Santos", 5, [0,1,2]);
let Aluno3 = new Aluno("Jose Santos", 10, [0,5,8]);
let Aluno4 = new Aluno("Antonio Silva", 4, [0,7,9]);
let Aluno5 = new Aluno("Maria dos santos", 6, [0,3,4]);

let listalunos = [Aluno1 , Aluno2, Aluno3,Aluno4,Aluno5]

console.log(listalunos)


// trete

const acum = [];

listalunos.forEach(aluno => {
  const match = acum.find(media => media.nome === aluno.nome);
  if (match) {
    match.soma += aluno.nota
    match.notas++;
  } else {
    aluno.soma = aluno.nota
    aluno.notas = 1;
    acum.push(aluno)
  }
});

const medias = [].map.call(acum, i => ({nome: i.nome, media: i.soma / i.notas}))

console.log(medias);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sinceramente, nem tentei entender qual o problema do seu código, eu acho mais simples reescrever o cálculo da média (que aliás, me parece desnecessariamente complicado).

A ideia é simples: para cada aluno você pega o array de notas, soma elas e divide pelo tamanho do array. Depois insere isso no array de médias, assim:

```js
function Aluno(nome, qtfaltas, notas) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.qtfaltas = qtfaltas;
    // *** OBS: mudei o nome para "notas", pois são várias notas e não uma só ***
    this.notas = notas;
}

let Aluno1 = new Aluno("Jose Silva", 0, [0, 10, 20]);
let Aluno2 = new Aluno("Paulo Santos", 5, [0, 1, 2]);
let Aluno3 = new Aluno("Jose Santos", 10, [0, 5, 8]);
let Aluno4 = new Aluno("Antonio Silva", 4, [0, 7, 9]);
let Aluno5 = new Aluno("Maria dos santos", 6, [0, 3, 4]);
let listaAlunos = [Aluno1, Aluno2, Aluno3, Aluno4, Aluno5];

const medias = [];
for (const aluno of listaAlunos) {
    let soma = 0;
    for (const nota of aluno.notas) {
        soma += nota;
    }
    medias.push({nome: aluno.nome, media: soma / aluno.notas.length });
}

console.log(medias);
```

Só isso. Nada de `map`, `forEach`, `find`, etc. E também mudei o nome da variável `notas`, afinal, ela é um array que pode ter várias notas, e colocar o nome no plural deixa isso mais claro. Pode parecer um detalhe bobo, mas [dar nomes melhores ajuda muito na hora de programar](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad).

Ah, também mudei `listalunos` para `listaAlunos` (faltou um "A" ali). De novo, pode parecer preciosismo, mas [arrumar esses pequenos detalhes no início pode fazer diferença no longo prazo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory).

E em vez de `for..of` (que [pode não funcionar em browsers mais antigos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#browser_compatibility)), você também poderia usar o `for` tradicional:

```js
const medias = [];
for (let i = 0; i < listaAlunos.length; i++) {
    const aluno = listaAlunos[i];
    let soma = 0;
    for (let j = 0; j < aluno.notas.length; j++) {
        soma += aluno.notas[j];
    }
    medias.push({ nome: aluno.nome, media: soma / aluno.notas.length });
}
```

---

Claro que você pode até poderia usar `map` para este caso, afinal para cada elemento do array de alunos você quer criar um elemento correspondente contendo o nome e a média:

```js
// para cada aluno, retorne um objeto com o nome e a média
const medias = listaAlunos.map(function(aluno) {
    let soma = 0;
    for (const nota of aluno.notas) {
        soma += nota;
    }
    return { nome: aluno.nome, media: soma / aluno.notas.length };
});
```

Claro que tem o custo extra do [*callback*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/112052), mas para poucos arrays pequenos a diferença é imperceptível. De qualquer forma, este é um caso em que o `map` é mais apropriado do que `forEach` (apesar de ambos percorrerem o array, [há diferenças](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/426824/112052): `map` retorna outro array com os resultados, que é exatamente o que você quer).

---

Por fim, vi que em algumas linhas você usou ponto-e-vírgula no final e em outras não. Eu sugiro que seja consistente e use sempre. Pode parecer "frescura", e sei que o JavaScript "aceita" o código sem ponto e vírgula e "funciona", mas isso evita algumas situações bizarras que podem ocorrer se você não usá-los, como [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1169596) e [essa](/q/432960/112052) (veja mais sobre isso [aqui](/q/3341/112052)).