# Busca em objeto com valor da chave sendo um array

Tags: javascript, array

Tenho o seguinte Objeto :

```
const mercado = {
  frutas: [
    {
      id: 1001,
      nome: "Maracujá",
      valorNutritivo: ["C"],
      predominante: ["JAN", "FEV", "MAR", "ABR", "MAI", "JUN", "JUL", "AGO", "DEZ"],
      preco: 3.40,
    },
    {
      id: 1002,
      nome: "Manga",
      valorNutritivo: ["A", "C", "B"],
      predominante: ["JAN", "FEV", "MAR", "OUT", "NOV", "DEZ"],
      preco: 2.30,
    },
    {
      id: 1003,
      nome: "Laranja",
      valorNutritivo: ["A", "C", "B"],
      predominante: ["MAI", "JUN", "JUL", "AGO", "SET", "OUT", "NOV"],
      preco: 2.30,
    },
    {
      id: 1004,
      nome: "Banana",
      valorNutritivo: ["A", "B1", "B2"],
      predominante: ["JAN", "FEV", "MAR", "SET", "OUT", "NOV", "DEZ"],
      preco: 2.30,
    },
    {
      id: 1006,
      nome: "Mamão",
      valorNutritivo: ["A", "C"],
      predominante: ["JAN", "FEV", "MAR", "ABR", "MAI", "JUN", "SET", "OUT", "NOV", "DEZ"],
      preco: 1.94,
    },
    {
      id: 1007,
      nome: "Maçã",
      valorNutritivo: ["C"],
      predominante: ["FEV", "MAR", "ABR", "MAI", "JUN", "JUL", "AGO", "SET"],
      preco: 4.16,
    },
    {
      id: 1008,
      nome: "Limão",
      valorNutritivo: ["C"],
      predominante: ["JAN", "AGO", "SET", "OUT", "NOV", "DEZ"],
      preco: 2.50,
    },
  ],
  descontoSemana: {
    seg: [1001, 1003, 1007],
    ter: [1002, 1004, 1008],
    qua: [1001, 1003, 1005],
    qui: [1002, 1004, 1006],
    sex: [1003, 1005, 1007],
    sab: [1004, 1006, 1008],
    dom: [1001, 1005, 1007],
  }
}
```

E tenho o seguinte código para completar:

```
const { descontoSemana, frutas } = mercado;

// complete a função diaDesconto, que ao receber o dia da semana ("seg", "ter", etc..),
// retorna uma lista com o nome das frutas que estão com desconto neste dia;
function diaDescontos(dia) {
  const descontos = Object.entries(descontoSemana);
  
  
}
diaDescontos('seg');
```

Ou seja, preciso verificar, através do parametro passado da função, sendo algum dia da semana do objeto `descontoSemana` Para ver quais as frutas que estão em promoção. Através do ID, que está de valor da chave do dia da semana, ex
seg: [iddafrutaempromo]

Mas não consigo acessar os valores desse objeto. Por se tratar de um valor em formato de um array. E por possuir mais de um 'valor'. Como posso comparar acessar estes Id's dentro do objeto descontoSemana para retornar o Nome da fruta que está em desconto no objeto frutas?

Obs: Como podem ver, estão dentro do mesmo objeto mercado.

Answer (score 1):

Ao contrário do que a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/535541/112052) afirmou, `map` **não** é o mais adequado (pelo menos não da forma que foi usado). `map` serve para aplicar uma função a todos os elementos de um array e **retorna outro array** com os resultados. Mas a outra resposta só usou `map` para percorrer o array e descartou o resultado, o que é um uso torto e completamente inadequado (ver mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/426824/112052)).

Além disso, é dito que a sua função deve **retornar** uma lista com o nome das frutas (e não imprimir).

Enfim, não precisa de `map`, dá para fazer apenas com um `for` simples (também acho que não precisa do `Object.entries` que tem no código da pergunta):

```js
const mercado = {
    frutas: [
        { id: 1001, nome: "Maracujá", valorNutritivo: ["C"], predominante: ["JAN", "FEV", "MAR", "ABR", "MAI", "JUN", "JUL", "AGO", "DEZ"], preco: 3.40 }, 
        { id: 1002, nome: "Manga", valorNutritivo: ["A", "C", "B"], predominante: ["JAN", "FEV", "MAR", "OUT", "NOV", "DEZ"], preco: 2.30 }, 
        { id: 1003, nome: "Laranja", valorNutritivo: ["A", "C", "B"], predominante: ["MAI", "JUN", "JUL", "AGO", "SET", "OUT", "NOV"], preco: 2.30 }, 
        { id: 1004, nome: "Banana", valorNutritivo: ["A", "B1", "B2"], predominante: ["JAN", "FEV", "MAR", "SET", "OUT", "NOV", "DEZ"], preco: 2.30 }, 
        { id: 1006, nome: "Mamão", valorNutritivo: ["A", "C"], predominante: ["JAN", "FEV", "MAR", "ABR", "MAI", "JUN", "SET", "OUT", "NOV", "DEZ"], preco: 1.94 }, 
        { id: 1007, nome: "Maçã", valorNutritivo: ["C"], predominante: ["FEV", "MAR", "ABR", "MAI", "JUN", "JUL", "AGO", "SET"], preco: 4.16 }, 
        { id: 1008, nome: "Limão", valorNutritivo: ["C"], predominante: ["JAN", "AGO", "SET", "OUT", "NOV", "DEZ"], preco: 2.50 }
    ],
    descontoSemana: {
        seg: [1001, 1003, 1007],
        ter: [1002, 1004, 1008],
        qua: [1001, 1003, 1005],
        qui: [1002, 1004, 1006],
        sex: [1003, 1005, 1007],
        sab: [1004, 1006, 1008],
        dom: [1001, 1005, 1007],
    }
};

function diaDescontos(dia) {
    let descontos = mercado.descontoSemana[dia]; // descontos do dia
    let frutasComDesconto = [];
    // para cada fruta do mercado
    for (const fruta of mercado.frutas) {
        if (descontos.includes(fruta.id)) { // se a fruta tem desconto
            frutasComDesconto.push(fruta.nome);
        }
    }
    // a função retorna a lista (não imprime)
    return frutasComDesconto;
}

// quem chama a função pode fazer o que quiser com o retorno (inclusive imprimir)
const frutasComDesconto = diaDescontos('seg');
console.log(frutasComDesconto); // [ 'Maracujá', 'Laranja', 'Maçã' ]
```

Além de não usar a ferramenta errada para o caso (`map`), esse código ainda tem a vantagem de ser mais eficiente ([veja aqui a comparação](https://jsbench.me/oqkwmehmm0/1)), pois o algoritmo da outra resposta (com `map`) faz o seguinte:

- para cada ID de fruta com desconto

  - percorre **todo** o array de frutas procurando a fruta que tem aquele ID
  - mesmo depois que encontra a fruta com o mesmo ID, **ele continua percorrendo o array de frutas** até o final (desnecessariamente, pois não há ID's repetidos e poderia parar assim que encontrasse)

Já o meu algoritmo faz o seguinte:

- para cada fruta do mercado

  - verifica se o ID está no array de descontos
  - o método `includes` retorna assim que o elemento é encontrado (veja o [algoritmo na especificação da linguagem](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.includes)), ou seja, ele **não faz iterações à toa** como o código da outra resposta

Por fim, ainda tem o fato de `map` ter chamadas de [*callback*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/112052) que têm o seu custo, o que não ocorre com o `for` - sim, o parâmetro que você passa para `map` é uma função de *callback*, e chamadas de função não são de graça. E claro, tem o problema já mencionado, que é o fato de `map` retornar outro array (e este ser descartado).

---

E se quiser, também pode usar o `for` "tradicional", que [fica ainda mais rápido](https://jsbench.me/oqkwmehmm0/2):

```js
function diaDescontos(dia) {
    let descontos = mercado.descontoSemana[dia];
    let frutasComDesconto = [];
    // em vez de for..of, use o for "tradicional"
    for (let i = 0; i < mercado.frutas.length; i++) {
        let fruta = mercado.frutas[i];
        if (descontos.includes(fruta.id)) {
            frutasComDesconto.push(fruta.nome);
        }
    }
    // a função retorna a lista (não imprime)
    return frutasComDesconto;
}
```

---

Claro que ainda não é o ideal, pois a função poderia receber o `mercado` como parâmetro (assim ela funcionaria para diferentes mercados, por exemplo), além de validar se existe array de descontos para o dia informado, etc.

E como um adendo, eu não sei se você pode modificar o objeto `mercado`, mas eu tornaria a estrutura mais amigável para buscas. Em vez de ter que verificar toda hora se o ID está em determinado array, talvez seja melhor reorganizar o mercado para ter um objeto que mapeia cada ID para sua respectiva fruta:

```js
const mercado = {
    frutas: [
        { id: 1001, nome: "Maracujá", valorNutritivo: ["C"], predominante: ["JAN", "FEV", "MAR", "ABR", "MAI", "JUN", "JUL", "AGO", "DEZ"], preco: 3.40 }, 
        { id: 1002, nome: "Manga", valorNutritivo: ["A", "C", "B"], predominante: ["JAN", "FEV", "MAR", "OUT", "NOV", "DEZ"], preco: 2.30 }, 
        { id: 1003, nome: "Laranja", valorNutritivo: ["A", "C", "B"], predominante: ["MAI", "JUN", "JUL", "AGO", "SET", "OUT", "NOV"], preco: 2.30 }, 
        { id: 1004, nome: "Banana", valorNutritivo: ["A", "B1", "B2"], predominante: ["JAN", "FEV", "MAR", "SET", "OUT", "NOV", "DEZ"], preco: 2.30 }, 
        { id: 1006, nome: "Mamão", valorNutritivo: ["A", "C"], predominante: ["JAN", "FEV", "MAR", "ABR", "MAI", "JUN", "SET", "OUT", "NOV", "DEZ"], preco: 1.94 }, 
        { id: 1007, nome: "Maçã", valorNutritivo: ["C"], predominante: ["FEV", "MAR", "ABR", "MAI", "JUN", "JUL", "AGO", "SET"], preco: 4.16 }, 
        { id: 1008, nome: "Limão", valorNutritivo: ["C"], predominante: ["JAN", "AGO", "SET", "OUT", "NOV", "DEZ"], preco: 2.50 }
    ],
    descontoSemana: {
        seg: [1001, 1003, 1007],
        ter: [1002, 1004, 1008],
        qua: [1001, 1003, 1005],
        qui: [1002, 1004, 1006],
        sex: [1003, 1005, 1007],
        sab: [1004, 1006, 1008],
        dom: [1001, 1005, 1007],
    }
};

function preparaMap(mercado) {
    // cria um objeto que mapeia cada ID para sua respectiva fruta
    mercado.mapFrutas = {};
    for (const fruta of mercado.frutas) {
        mercado.mapFrutas[fruta.id] = fruta;
    }
}

function diaDescontos(dia) {
    // **Agora sim** map é adequado
    return mercado.descontoSemana[dia].map(idFruta => mercado.mapFrutas[idFruta].nome);
}

// só chama uma vez
preparaMap(mercado);

console.log(diaDescontos('seg')); // [ 'Maracujá', 'Laranja', 'Maçã' ]
console.log(diaDescontos('qui')); // [ 'Manga', 'Banana', 'Mamão' ]
```

Assim, eu não preciso mais buscar o ID no array, basta acessá-lo diretamente usando o `mapFrutas`. E **agora sim** faz sentido usar `map`, pois o que queremos é **mapear** cada ID com desconto para a sua respectiva fruta no `mapFrutas` (e eu uso o valor retornado por `map` como o resultado da função). E como agora não precisamos percorrer o array para procurar pela fruta, [ficou ainda mais rápido](https://jsbench.me/oqkwmehmm0/3).

Obviamente que a função pode ser melhorada para validar se a fruta e/ou o dia existem mesmo, etc.

---

Por fim, é claro que para arrays pequenos rodando poucas vezes a diferença será insignificante (e provavelmente imperceptível), e tudo isso talvez não passe de micro-otimização. Mas é interessante saber desses detalhes, em vez de simplesmente usar algo só porque "funciona". Cada ferramenta tem seu uso, e usar `map` para percorrer o array (como indicado pela outra resposta) é usar a ferramenta errada para a tarefa (eu só usei no último exemplo porque antes eu modifiquei a estrutura do `mercado` para que ela ficasse adequada, tanto que ficou bem mais rápido - ao custo de gastar mais espaço para o `mapFrutas` - ou seja, tem que saber quando usar cada coisa).

Answer (score -3):

Pra esse tipo de situação o método map é indicado, inclusive podendo colocar vários em cascata. No caso, a sua função precisa percorrer os IDs do dia da semana e depois percorrer as frutas para ver qual tem esse ID e e pegar o nome dela. Segue o código da solução:

```
 function diaDescontos(dia) {
  let frutas = mercado.frutas;
  let frutasComDesconto = [];
  mercado.descontoSemana[dia].map(fruta => {
    frutas.map(f => {
      if(f.id == fruta){
        frutasComDesconto += (f.nome + "\n");
      }
    })
  });
  console.log(frutasComDesconto);
 }
 diaDescontos('seg');
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Eu estava quebrando a cabeça com esse problema. Consegui entender cada linha do seu código! Me abriu a mente! Valeu Davi!!

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).