# Conversão de string em data resulta no dia anterior em alguns casos

Tags: javascript, data

Recebo um array contendo a data de criação neste formato: `2021-11-30T00:18:50.000000Z`.

Gostaria de informar somente o dia, então estou usando `getDate()`, mas quando percorro o array, o resultado informado está incorreto.

Este é o array:

```
[ { "id": 1, "created_at": "2021-11-30T00:10:58.000000Z"},
{ "id": 2, "created_at": "2021-11-30T00:18:03.000000Z"},
{ "id": 3, "created_at": "2021-11-30T00:18:50.000000Z"},
{ "id": 5, "created_at": "2021-11-30T00:28:02.000000Z"},
{ "id": 6,"created_at": "2021-12-01T23:38:40.000000Z"},
{ "id": 7, "created_at": "2021-12-01T23:39:06.000000Z"},
{ "id": 8, "created_at": "2021-12-02T23:39:16.000000Z"},
{ "id": 9, "created_at": "2021-12-02T23:42:47.000000Z"},
{ "id": 10,"created_at": "2021-12-02T00:10:12.000000Z",}]
```

Estou usando a seguinte função:

```
InformarDia(array) {
            var ArrayDia = array;            
            var result = [];
            ArrayDia.reduce(function (res, value) {
                if (!res[value.id]) {
                    res[value.id] = {
                        id: value.id,                               
                        Dia: new Date(value.created_at).getDate(),                       
                    };
                    result.push(res[value.id])
                }
                return res;
            }, {});
            return result
        },
```

O resultado que a função retorna:

```
Resultado:                       Resultado esperado

[ { "id": 1, "Dia": 29 },      [ { "id": 1, "Dia": 30 },   
{ "id": 2, "Dia": 29 },          { "id": 2, "Dia": 30 },
{ "id": 3, "Dia": 29 },          { "id": 3, "Dia": 30 },
{ "id": 5, "Dia": 29 },          { "id": 5, "Dia": 30 },
{ "id": 6, "Dia": 1 },           { "id": 6, "Dia": 1 },
{ "id": 7, "Dia": 1 },           { "id": 7, "Dia": 1 },
{ "id": 8, "Dia": 1 },           { "id": 8, "Dia": 2 },
{ "id": 9, "Dia": 1 },           { "id": 9, "Dia": 2 },
{ "id": 10, "Dia": 1 }]          { "id": 10, "Dia": 2 }]
```

A partir do "id: 8" era para a função retornar "Dia: 2" mais ela retorna "Dia: 1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está passando para o construtor de `Date` uma string no [formato ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), e o "Z" no final indica que a data/hora está em [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

O problema é que os *getters* (como `getDate()`) retornam os valores de acordo com o timezone do ambiente no qual o código roda (seja o *browser*, ou o Node, não importa, sempre terá algum timezone configurado e é este que é usado para converter os valores - mais detalhes [aqui](https://hkotsubo.github.io/blog/2021-11-29/entendendo-o-date-do-javascript)).

Então o que acontece é que o seu ambiente possui um timezone que provavelmente está com uma (ou mais) horas a menos em relação a UTC, por isso alguns casos acabam ficando no dia anterior.

No seu caso, a solução é relativamente simples, pois um `Date` possui *getters* que retornam o valor em UTC. Ou seja, basta trocar `getDate` para `getUTCDate`:

```js
var array = [
    { "id": 1, "created_at": "2021-11-30T00:10:58.000000Z"},
    { "id": 2, "created_at": "2021-11-30T00:18:03.000000Z"},
    { "id": 3, "created_at": "2021-11-30T00:18:50.000000Z"},
    { "id": 5, "created_at": "2021-11-30T00:28:02.000000Z"},
    { "id": 6, "created_at": "2021-12-01T23:38:40.000000Z"},
    { "id": 7, "created_at": "2021-12-01T23:39:06.000000Z"},
    { "id": 8, "created_at": "2021-12-02T23:39:16.000000Z"},
    { "id": 9, "created_at": "2021-12-02T23:42:47.000000Z"},
    { "id": 10, "created_at": "2021-12-02T00:10:12.000000Z"}
];

function InformarDia(array) {
    var ArrayDia = array;            
    var result = [];
    ArrayDia.reduce(function (res, value) {
        if (!res[value.id]) {
            res[value.id] = {
                id: value.id,
                Dia: new Date(value.created_at).getUTCDate(), // <-- AQUI
            };
            result.push(res[value.id]);
        }
        return res;
    }, {});
    return result;
}

console.log(InformarDia(array));
```

---

Outro ponto é que estou achando um "exagero" usar `reduce`. Se os id's não se repetem e você quer criar um array no qual cada elemento corresponde a um elemento do array original, então na verdade o que você quer é **mapear** cada elemento para um novo valor correspondente, portanto [usar `map` me parece bem mais adequado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/426824/112052) para este caso:

```js
var array = [
    { "id": 1, "created_at": "2021-11-30T00:10:58.000000Z"},
    { "id": 2, "created_at": "2021-11-30T00:18:03.000000Z"},
    { "id": 3, "created_at": "2021-11-30T00:18:50.000000Z"},
    { "id": 5, "created_at": "2021-11-30T00:28:02.000000Z"},
    { "id": 6, "created_at": "2021-12-01T23:38:40.000000Z"},
    { "id": 7, "created_at": "2021-12-01T23:39:06.000000Z"},
    { "id": 8, "created_at": "2021-12-02T23:39:16.000000Z"},
    { "id": 9, "created_at": "2021-12-02T23:42:47.000000Z"},
    { "id": 10, "created_at": "2021-12-02T00:10:12.000000Z"}
];

function InformarDia(array) {
    // mapeia cada elemento do array para outro contendo o id e o dia
    // a função retorna este novo array
    return array.map(function (elemento) {
        return {
            id: elemento.id,
            Dia: new Date(elemento.created_at).getUTCDate()
        };
    });
}

console.log(InformarDia(array));
```

---

Para entender melhor sobre como funciona o `Date` do JavaScript, leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/456089/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/455437/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/408160/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/416172/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/469717/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/344030/112052).

Comment: Você é god de mais, valeu

Answer (score 0):

Não consegui reproduzir exatamente o problema com o código que postaste. Em vez disso, o resultado que tive executando aqui a tua função com o array passado foi esse:

```
0: {id: 1, Dia: 29}
1: {id: 2, Dia: 29}
2: {id: 3, Dia: 29}
3: {id: 5, Dia: 29}
4: {id: 6, Dia: 1}
5: {id: 7, Dia: 1}
6: {id: 8, Dia: 2}
7: {id: 9, Dia: 2}
8: {id: 10, Dia: 1}
```

Dada as datas e a minha Timezone (que é no Brasil, UTC-0300), todos os resultados estão corretos. Talvez tu tenhas achado estranho, por exemplo, o dia 10 e os dias até o 5 estarem "no dia anterior", mas na verdade, isso se dá por conta da Timezone setada no array para UTC (é o `Z` no final do array). Quando executo, reduzo 3 da hora por conta do fuso, que dá no dia anterior nesses casos. Se o teu array de datas for nesse formato:

```
2021-11-30T00:10:58
```

As datas não são afetadas pelo timezone, e provavelmente tu terás o resultado desejado.